# Howto access data held in widget options when inside a widget event handler

Tags: jquery-ui

I have data held in the options variable, but in an event (OnChange) of a select list 
this refers to the DOMElement and therefore this.options refers to the list of  objects.

everywhere else I can have

```
var o = this.options;
```

but this is no use in this context.

How to get/set the widget information ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`this._on()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_on) to bind the handler. This method is provided by the jQuery UI widget factory and will make sure that within the handler function, `this` always refers to the widget instance.

```js
_create: function () {
    ...
    this._on(this.selectElement, {
        change: "_onChange" // Note: function name must be passed as a string!
    });
},
_onChange: function (event) {
    // 'this' is now the widget instance.
},
```

Comment: changed answer to this as origianal answer (from myself) has been superceeded.

Comment: If you're extending a widget with a custom name then the event name will be: [my custom widget name in lower case][event name] So if you're extending sortable to mySortable and want to bind on the update event, it will be: "mysortableupdate" : "_onChange"

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply do this in the event handler (e.g. for the autocomplete widget)

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   var options = jQuery(event.target).data("autocomplete").options;

   ...
}
```

Comment: jQuery(ev.target).data("autocomplete") is undefined, for:
jQuery(ev.target).data("autocomplete").options;

Answer (score -1):

```
(function($){
    $.widget(
        "ui.my_ui_widget", 
        {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            _init : function(){
                var o = this.options; // 2
                o.context = this;
                ...
                // 3
                $('#'+o.id).bind('change', {context:this}, this.on_change );
                ...
            },
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            on_change: function(event) {
                var context = event.data.context; // 4
            var o       = context.options;

                o.id = ''; // 5

                var sel = this; // event handler context
                var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
                if (selectedIndex < 0) return;

                o.id = sel.options[selectedIndex].value; // 5

                context.update_ui(); // 6
            },
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
        } 
    );
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.extend( $.ui.my_ui_widget, {
        getter       : "id",
        getterSetter : "xxx, yyy",

        defaults : {
               ...
             context   : undefined, // 1
             ...
             on_change : undefined,
               ...
            }
        }
    );
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_ui_widget').each( function(i) {
            var id = this.id;
            var mode = '';

            try{
                mode = this.attributes['mode'].value;
            } catch(err) {
                mode = 'unlinked';
            }

            $('#'+id).my_ui_widget( {id:id, mode:mode} );
        }
    );
});
```

1. Enable context from the beginning
2. Remember the widget's this as context (or self if preferred)
3. Pass the context in the jquery way to event handler
4. Extract when needed on the handler side
5. Access the widget data
6. Call widget methods as needed

Comment: ev.data is undefined, for:
var context = ev.data.context; //4